# i have many images in array , i want fadein fadeout on imageview repeatedly

Tags: ios, iphone

```
[super viewDidLoad];

imgView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_slide_1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_slide_2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_slide_3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_slide_4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_slide_5.png"];
```

[start animation];

fadein,fadeout for this images repeatedly

Comment: Please do not delete your questions and then repost them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677895/fade-in-an-image-in-xcode-automatically) - onComplete you would set the new image and fade it back in